# Problems occurs during update

Tags: updates

```
Err:6 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease          
  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 1F3045A5DF7587C3 Skype Linux Client Repository <se-um@microsoft.com>
Reading package lists... Done
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 1F3045A5DF7587C3 Skype Linux Client Repository <se-um@microsoft.com>
W: Failed to fetch https://repo.skype.com/deb/dists/stable/InRelease  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 1F3045A5DF7587C3 Skype Linux Client Repository <se-um@microsoft.com>
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

This is coming when I am going to update my Ubuntu via terminal.
Could you please suggest to me how can I update my Ubuntu?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please read [ask] then [edit] your question accordingly. What are you upgrading from and to and what steps did you take to accomplish the upgrade will be particularly helpful.

Comment: @24601 actually I want to update my version and I am using the command sudo apt-get update, then these errors are coming.